# Как убрать часть кода с внешнего сайта с помощью js?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, плагин

с помощью внешнего сайта подключили плагин CPAFeed на WordPress, через css сайта он не редактируется (css плагина лежит на сайте плагина). Как с помощью написания своего js убрать из верстки лишние блоки этого плагина?

примеры классов

Comment: Зачем тут js? Перекройте его css своим, и все дела.

Comment: он не перекрывает! сразу же попробовал

Comment: Не умеете перекрывать, все решаемо. Без конкретного примера и вашего кода точнее ничего не сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('селектор элемента').remove();
});
```

НО если контент лежит в iframe - тебе ничего не поможет)

Comment: лежит в iframe :(

Comment: если знаешь PHP и умеешь юзать curl - можешь примочку зафигачить, но не советую, ибо это будет как-то сильно ущербно и если там есть AJAX - то еще и работать не будет)

Answer (score 1):

- перебейте их стили своими с пометкой !important
- через js:

```js
document.querySelector('тут селектор').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: через !important пробовал, не получилось